# Where might the dbus development (.h) files be for RHEL5?

Tags: rhel, development, d-bus

A quick search from yum for dbus fails to turn up the devel related package that should provide dbus.h et al.  Anybody have experience locating the relevant package?  Should I just resort to getting the dbus source itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to set the subscription for the machine.  In the RHN panel, select the machine and click on "Alter Channel Subscriptions."  Check one of the channel entitlements.  Run yum update and try again.

Answer (score 3):

`yum provides '*/dbus.h'` will tell you what packages will provide dbus.h. In this case, its dbus-devel.

Comment: Plus one for the wildcard.  Provides simply states no matches.  Attempting to install dbus-devel results in no such package.  Is there something on RHN that has to be switched on?  Is there a repository or the like missing?

Comment: I use CentOS but the repo layout should be the same as RHEL AFAIK. dbus-devel is part of the updates repo which should be enabled by default. Can you get any packages from the updates repo? dbus is part of that repo so if you can install that you should be able to install dbus-devel. If nothing from updates is being downloaded make sure its not disabled someplace in /etc/yum.repos.d/. `fgrep '[updates]' /etc/yum.repos.d/*` will tell you where it is. Make sure there's no exclude line excluding it in /etc/yum.conf or anywhere in /etc/yum.repos.d/*

Comment: I get no matches on the search you specified.  The only file in yum.repos.d is rhel-debuginfo.repo.  yum.conf contains only a section named [main], and the only thing interesting listed looks like:  distroverpkg=redhat-release  Is there a stanza for the update repo I can add?

Answer (score 1):

Using `source` instead of `install` worked for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get source dbus
```

Comment: RHEL doesn't ship with apt-get AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Red hat development packages usually end in "-devel"

Have you had any luck with `dbus-devel`?

Comment: No luck.  Is there a repository or option that needs to be enabled?  There are other packages listed with -devel, so some are there.